# document.ready is getting called multiple times

Tags: php, jquery

Within my php app I have multiple templates that get combined to form a single page. so say your on the about us page, the template would look like this

```
<?php
    $this->render("header.php");
?>

my about us page

<?php
  $this->render("footer.php");
?>
```

which is just a fancy way of doing an include(). However, header.php has some javascript that gets ran on document.ready via the jquery framework, and so does the page that requires the header. so you have something like this

```
<?php
    $this->render("header.php"); // has its own $(document).ready
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          console.log("test");
     });
 </script>
my about us page

<?php
  $this->render("footer.php");
?>
```

The bug that I'm experiencing is that document.ready is getting called once for every document.ready on the page. in the above case console shows

test

test

If I comment out the rendering of header.php, the document.ready gets called just once like I want.

Besides using a semaphore, is a better way to prevent this? I tried buffering the output, but that doesn't seem to work.

**Edit: added final output per request**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          // do some javascript like highlighting 
          // form elements with specific classes
     });
</script>
  display header here 

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          console.log("test");
     });
 </script>
my about us page

display footer
```

Comment: What's the HTML output of this? The PHP is almost certainly irrelevant?

Comment: I'm not from your question if you want to change something in the php or in the javascript.

Comment: If your putting it in the header file and the body its going to get called twice isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried running your final output locally and only one "test" message appears in the console, as expected.

Are you including any other JS libraries? There may be some code in the JS which you have edited out that is causing this.

Comment: Within one of the plugins, the author was doing a 

$(elm).wrapInner('<div></div>');

which would wrap any script tag also within the div. Thus the page would load and all the document.ready-s would run which would in turn run this plugin. Now this plugin rebuilds small sections of the dom(by doing the wrapInner), which triggered the second running of the javascript within that rebuilt section. After rewriting how they did the wrapInner, everything is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I put together this demo code but wasn unable to reproduce the issue... hopefully it helps you out...

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          // do some javascript like highlighting 
          // form elements with specific classes
      $('.some-element').css('background', '#eec');
     });
</script>

display header here 

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('body').append("<p>test</p>");
     });
 </script>

<p class='some-element'>
my about us page
display footer
</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```